# Can I prevent re-rendering a component if it's parent changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the VDOM changes from

```
<Foo><Bar1><Baz id={123}/></Bar1></Foo>
```

to

```
<Foo><Bar2><Baz id={123}/></Bar2></Foo>
```

Foo renders either Bar1, Bar2 or something completely different. Bar1 and Bar2 always render to `<Baz id={123}/>`, but Foo might also render Bar3 which renders to `<Baz id={420}/>`.

Unnecessary re-rendering of Baz is very costly. Baz returns true in shouldComponentUpdate if and only if id changes.

Is it possible to prevent re-rendering Baz when Foo decides to render Bar1 instead of Bar2? Or somehow re-use the component? Kludges are welcome too.

Comment: Can you not add a key to Baz? Would that not encourage React to re-use the component?

Comment: I can, will test if it works tomorrow

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

This is what I am meaning.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I'm familiar with using key props in general, but didn't know changing the key of Baz would prevent re-rendering here? And didn't get that picture from (re-)reading that manual page either, but I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: @eagle12 nopes, it still re-renders Baz. Pardon the compile-to-js but for example here http://dpaste.com/26VPZV1  Baz gets re-rendered when the button is clicked

Comment: http://dpaste.com/3S7SEN4  tried this one and it seems to work, just fearing that I'll shoot myself on the foot.